# uniform i.i.d test consistent?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, hypothesis-testing

$X_k \sim U(0,L)$ i.i.d; $H_0: L=L_0 ~ H_1: L \ne L_0$; $L,a \in(0,1)$ is a test with the following power function:

$P_n(L_0)= P( max_{k=1,..,n}X_k>L_0~\cup~ max_{k=1,..n}X_k<L_0*a^{1/n})$. How do I show that this test is consistent? So far I only managed to use the properties of the $X_k$ and the fact that both sets are disjoint to arrive at $P_n(L_0)=1+(\frac{L_0}{L})^n(a-1)$. I'm not really sure how to show that the second term converges to 0, assuming it is possible at all and I don't need another approach entirely.

Comment: You're pretty much there. Your expression is the power function for $0\leq L_0 < L$, so you only have to take limits as $n\to\infty$. What happens to the original power function if $L_0 < 0$ or $L_0 > L$?

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks, gotcha. I was so caught up with looking at the finished term of the pfunction that I forgot to look at what happens at the very start inside of the brackets.